# Installation of custom made shared library files/ Or any alternatives to it

Tags: java, c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have an app(for CentOs) that uses two custom made shared libraries "libMyInit.so" (linked with libMyInit.so.1 and  libMyInit.so.1.0.1) and libMyUtil.so (linked with libMyUtil.so.1 and libMyUtil.so libMyUtil.so.1.0.1). Thes are present inside the app packaging like MyApp/bin/libMyInit.so & MyApp/bin/util/libMyUtil.so along with their respective linked libraries.
When I have to run the app  I have to explictly add the above mentioned paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH without which it give the error like:
`ERROR:Unable to load native MyUtil library. Reason: no MyUtil in java.library.path`.

Is there any way I can avoid  the manual adding of libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?
Something that I can do at compile time of shared libraries or later so that the custom made .so libraries are found in the java.library.path ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way of doing this, is to use a custom `System.loadLibrary` in the static part of your classes. Have a look at my Java portaudio bindings [here@github](https://github.com/rjeschke/jpa/tree/master/src/java/com/github/rjeschke/jpa), especially at the `LoadLibrary` and `JPA` classes.

The `LoadLibrary` class selects a native library based on OS type and architecture, unpacks the lib from its JAR into the temp folder and loads it from there.

`JPA` now just has to call `LoadLibrary.load` and everything works automagically on all supported OSs and you only need one single JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to copy those libraries to one of /usr/lib, /lib, /usr/local/lib directories.